# how can i use jmeter to send binary data by post

Tags: jmeter

i want to send an picture and some parameters(key=value) to server by post.
now i use jmeter(version：2.13) to try to finish this job . i have set the "content-type" as "application/octet-stream" and also input some parameters and it's value into the boxes under the "paramete" tag. Also i've put the filepath of a jpg file and set the MIME type as "application/octet-stream".
But jmeter send those parameters as form-data not as binary data
Do anyone can help me with this ? i'll be deeply grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you **need** to have `Content-Type` header to be `application/octet-stream` you have to uncheck "Use multipart/form-data for POST" box.

As per [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request):

> When using multipart/form-data, this suppresses the Content-Type and Content-Transfer-Encoding headers; only the Content-Disposition header is sent.

If you still need the "multipart" you can append your parameters to "Path" like:

```
/upload/url?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Check out [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide for more information on simulating file operations in your Jmeter test.

Comment: >you have to uncheck "Use multipart/form-data for POST" box.
i didn't check the "Use multipart/form-data for POST" box .And i want to send parameters which are put in the body not in the url path. 
i tried to put parameters  under the "body" tag but jmeter didn't send them.(the picture was send as i wished)